# automaticaly set ttl at router startup

Tags: linux, router, dd-wrt

I have following startup (Administration-Commands-Startup script) script in my dd-wrt router

```
iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -o `get_wanface` -j TTL --ttl-set 128
```

However it does not work. I suppose startup script run when iptables is not working yet. Are there any way to set ttl every time when router starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iptables with that command does not set ttl at router start-up

it sets the ttl for "every" packet at POSTROUTING that means when exiting the routing engine...

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, I am not so good with `iptables`. What I want to say is that command does not work from startup script, however it works when I run it after router started from ssh session.

Comment: iptables is an interface to the kernel net-filter/router engine, then the command you mention tells the kernel net-filter/router that for every net packet that leaves the routing engine "mangle" (manipulate/set) the TTL field to a certain value.
Remeber it is the kernel who does the things, iptables is the way you tell the kernel what to do with the packets.
When the init script is run the kernel is already working then try to see if the command is well conformed and really present on a script that is really run on init

Comment: How can I get current ttl value from `iptables`?

Comment: you have to list iptables tables i.e
"iptables iptables -nL -v --line-numbers -t mangle"